# html flag in reactjs render method

Tags: html, reactjs

Please find my below code. How can i show html flag in reactjs render method ().

```
<td>{ this.props.flag=="true" ? {&#9872;} : null} </td>
```

Its throwing error.

Comment: Write it like this: `<td>{ this.props.flag=="true" ? <span>&#9872</span> : null} </td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a

```
<td>{ this.props.flag=="true" ? <span>&#9872;</span> : null} </td>
```

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. I want to increase the size of the flag.. can you suggest.

Comment: <span style={{fontSize:50}}>&#9872;</span>

Comment: How i can add color for the flag..??

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: *Corrected as per comment below*

You can simply wrap it in a `span`

or

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, for example :

```
{this.props.flag ? <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: '&#9872;' }} /> : null}
```

I recommend reading more about it [here](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

Comment: We can write without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, like this: `<span>&#9872</span>`

Comment: That's correct, i'll update my answer to not be misleading, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It will render just fine if you use unicode `\u2690` instead of HTML encoding, e.g.

```
<td>{ this.props.flag && "\u2690" }</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36Lrv0nL/

Comment: I want to increase the size of the flag. how can i do that..?

Comment: Using `font-size` CSS property, for example `<td style={{ fontSize : 48 }}>` https://jsfiddle.net/36Lrv0nL/1/